# Unicode Keyboard Integration TinyMCE

Tags: unicode, keyboard, tinymce

I want to develop a Unicode based (پشتو) language text editor with tinyMCE. I already have a keyboard which works perfect in my dictionary application here

**http://thepashto.com**

Now i want to integrate this keyboard to work with TinyMCE, it has some java script function which executed on Keyup event of the text area, when i remove the editor it works fine with normal text area but stop working after TinyMCE integration.

Please help in this regard!

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that tinymce is not equal your textarea. On initialization tinymce hides the textarea and creates a contenteditable iframe. You will need to bind your events to this iframe (or the iframe body) in order to be able to react correctly.

Addressing the former textarea will not work because what you enter is entered in the iframe and the hidden textarea gets updated from time to time with the actuyl editor content.

Comment: Sounds good! Can you tell me how can i submit this value to tinyMCE?

Comment: tinymce.get('your_textarea_id').execCommand('insertHTML',false,'text');

Comment: Where should i put this line?
In TinyMCE class or html where i have to display?

Comment: Sorry dear, i am not getting you. The place i want to display the content is iframe, whereas the keyboard working in textarea. When we call the function tinyMCE.init, so the textarea converted into iframe, how can i show the text here?

Comment: try  
tinymce.get('your_textarea_id').execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'text'); - this is the way using the tinymce api to insert content into the editor at the current caret location. the keyboard is not working in a textarea! please specify what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: this is the editor, http://thepashto.com/editor which is not working you can check it with firebug, and the working example is thepashto.com

Comment: i can see the editor, but i guess you want to insert arabic letters(?) in this case you will have to catch the predefined tinymce events onKeyDown, onKeyPress, onKeyUp and insert the desired arabic letter there while stopping the default action (inserting western characters).this can be done using the tinymce configuration parameter setup in combination with onKeyDown etc.

Comment: Yes i want to insert arabic words!
Thanks for your co-operation dude.

Comment: its a bit complex but i will try to diagnose it with your technique.